# Advanced filtering of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
import xlwings as xw

from collections import Counter

wb = xw.Book('Test.xlsx')

sheet = xw.sheets.active

SKUs = sheet.range('A2:C693').value

list_of_prob = sheet.range('D2:D693').value
list_of_prob = [float(i) for i in list_of_prob]

SKUs = random.choices(SKUs, weights = list_of_prob, k=20)

for item in zip(SKUs):
         print (item)
```

I coded the following program (above) which outputs an order picking list of 20 items based on their probability:

```
(['Item91', 10.0, 1.0],)
(['Item482', 6.0, 15.0],)
(['Item533', 8.0, 17.0],)
(['Item63', 7.0, 2.0],)
(['Item50', 5.0, 5.0],)
(['Item14', 2.0, 2.0],)
(['Item145', 1.0, 6.0],)
(['Item225', 6.0, 9.0],)
(['Item23', 3.0, 2.0],)
(['Item33', 4.0, 2.0],)
(['Item47', 5.0, 4.0],)
(['Item88', 9.0, 4.0],)
(['Item8', 1.0, 4.0],)
(['Item1', 1.0, 1.0],)
(['Item13', 2.0, 2.0],)
(['Item21', 3.0, 1.0],)
(['Item86', 9.0, 3.0],)
(['Item205', 5.0, 6.0],)
(['Item1', 1.0, 1.0],)
(['Item67', 7.0, 4.0],)
```

Every item has two numbers that correspond to the aisle and slot in the aisle (in a warehouse). The aim now is to filter the list that all duplicate aisles are removed and only left with the furthest slot for the corresponding aisle.

Example: aisle 1 has four items to be picked. To calculate the order picker’s travel time (return routing policy), I only need the location of the furthest item. That would be slot 6 in aisle 1. Thus I want to filter all the aisle 1 duplicates and only keep ([1.0, 6.0],).

Thus for all aisles I want the following list:

From this:

```
([10.0, 1.0],)
([6.0, 15.0],)
([8.0, 17.0],)
([7.0, 2.0],)
([5.0, 5.0],)
([2.0, 2.0],)
([1.0, 6.0],)
([6.0, 9.0],)
([3.0, 2.0],)
([4.0, 2.0],)
([5.0, 4.0],)
([9.0, 4.0],)
([1.0, 4.0],)
([1.0, 1.0],)
([2.0, 2.0],)
([3.0, 1.0],)
([9.0, 3.0],)
([5.0, 6.0],)
([1.0, 1.0],)
([7.0, 4.0],)
```

To this:

```
([10.0, 1.0],)
([6.0, 15.0],)
([8.0, 17.0],)
([2.0, 2.0],)
([1.0, 6.0],)
([3.0, 2.0],)
([4.0, 2.0],)
([9.0, 4.0],)
([5.0, 6.0],)
([7.0, 4.0],)
```

I did manage to find a solution in excel. First removing all duplicates and then with the remaining duplicates look for the max value of the corresponding value. Is there a good way to achieve this kind of "advanced" filtering in Python?

Comment: in python if you use `set` it will remove duplicate items and python has a `max` function you might want to look at..

Comment: Why do you use `float` instead of `int` for aisle and slot? Can those values be fractions?

Comment: @johnashu thanks for your reply. I'm going to play with that a bit and try to figure something out.

Comment: @Håken Lid thanks for your reply. It is not possible that the aisles or slots are fractions. They indeed should be integers. However, xlwings imports them als floats. It is not a major problem but i still have to figure out how to import them as integers to make everything look nicer.

Comment: I strongly recommend looking at pandas module for processing data like that

Comment: drop duplicates.. https://medium.com/@kasiarachuta/dealing-with-duplicates-in-pandas-dataframe-789894a28911

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary to keep track of which rows you've seen so far and what the maximum slot number for each row is:

```
results = {}
for item, row, slot in SKUs:
    if results.get(row, 0) < slot:
        results[row] = slot
```

Note that I didn't use `zip` like you are in your example code, since that seems to be pointlessly wrapping your data in 1-tuples that you don't need.

If you need a list of row, max-slot pairs at the end, use `list(results.items())`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im going to look into the use of a dictionary as Python is new for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pandas-based solution as suggested by others above. It uses sql-like grouping.

```
import pandas as pd

datin = [['Item91', 10.0, 1.0],
         ['Item482', 6.0, 15.0],
         ['Item533', 8.0, 17.0],
         ['Item63', 7.0, 2.0],
         ['Item50', 5.0, 5.0],
         ['Item14', 2.0, 2.0],
         ['Item145', 1.0, 6.0],
         ['Item225', 6.0, 9.0],
         ['Item23', 3.0, 2.0],
         ['Item33', 4.0, 2.0],
         ['Item47', 5.0, 4.0],
         ['Item88', 9.0, 4.0],
         ['Item8', 1.0, 4.0],
         ['Item1', 1.0, 1.0],
         ['Item13', 2.0, 2.0],
         ['Item21', 3.0, 1.0],
         ['Item86', 9.0, 3.0],
         ['Item205', 5.0, 6.0],
         ['Item1', 1.0, 1.0],
         ['Item67', 7.0, 4.0]]

pd.DataFrame(datin, columns=['Item', 'Aisle', 'Slot']).groupby(by='Aisle', as_index=False)['Slot'].max().values.tolist()
```

Comment: @Karim.C - do consider accepting a response if one of them answers your question.  Cheers!